# Create new dataframe by dividing all possibles columns combination from another table

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-wrangling

I'm struggling to find an easy a fast solution to create a new data frame by multiplying all "group" of columns between them.

Data for example

```
a1 <- rnorm(n = 10)
b1 <- rnorm(n = 10)
c1 <- rnorm(n = 10)
a2 <- rnorm(n = 10)
b2 <- rnorm(n = 10)
c2 <- rnorm(n = 10)
```

For example in this in my initial datatable

```
Original <- data.frame(
  date = seq(today()-9, today(), by = 1),
  a1 = a1,
  b1 = b1,
  c1 = c1,
  a2 = a2,
  b2 = b2,
  c2 = c2)
```

and this datatable is what I would like to achieve (e.i., columns with all the possible combination between the columns that end with a 1 and columns with all the possible combination between the columns that end with a 2)

```
Objective <- data.frame(
  date = seq(today()-9, today(), by = 1),
  b1a1 = b1*a1,
  c1a1 = c1*a1,
  c1b1 = c1*b1,
  b2c2 = b2*c2,
  b2a2 = b2*a2,
  c2a2 = c2*a2)
```

I tried with loops but it's not a very elegant and efficient solution; or at least mine wasn't. A solution using the tidyverse would be very welcome

Thanks in advance

I.T

Comment: Seems like an odd use for tidyverse related packages. I find them very hard to understand (specially for beginners) when used in such specific cases. I would try something along using expand.grid to find out all the combinations between a1, b1, c1, a2.. etc. Once every combination is defined, it should be easy to define those new columns. I'll write a proper answer later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very good question.  A `tidyverse` approach.  This approach will have combination of uneven number of columns per group. Explanation -

- Data is divided into a list with each sub-group as a separate item in the list.  For this division

  - Firstly, the data is pivoted long using `pivot_longer`
  - then a dummy group (sub-group identification) column in created using `gsub`.  You may use `str_replace` too.
- list created using `dplyr::group_split`
- data in all items reshaped back to its original form using `tidyr::pivot_wider` inside `purrr::map` now
- thereafter all individual items of list -

  - first combined using `combn` and `Reduce`.  You may also use `purrr::reduce` here
  - secondly names of new columns generated using same `combn` and `Reduce`
  - these names bound above matrix into a named dataframe.
- lastly, using `purrr::reduce` in conjunction with `dplyr::left_join` list is converted back to intended shape

```r
set.seed(123)
a1 <- rnorm(n = 10)
b1 <- rnorm(n = 10)
c1 <- rnorm(n = 10)
a2 <- rnorm(n = 10)
b2 <- rnorm(n = 10)
c2 <- rnorm(n = 10)

Original <- data.frame(
  date = seq(Sys.Date()-9, Sys.Date(), by = 1),
  a1 = a1,
  b1 = b1,
  c1 = c1,
  a2 = a2,
  b2 = b2,
  c2 = c2)

library(tidyverse)
Original %>% pivot_longer(!date) %>%
  mutate(grp = gsub('^\\D*(\\d)+$', '\\1', name)) %>%
  group_split(grp, .keep = F) %>%
  map(~ .x %>% pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)) %>%
  map(~ combn(.x[-1], 2, FUN = Reduce, f = `*`) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
        setNames(combn(names(.x[-1]), 2, FUN = Reduce, f = paste0)) %>% cbind(.x[1], .)) %>%
  reduce(~left_join(.x, .y, by = 'date'))

         date        a1b1        a1c1        b1c1        a2b2         a2c2         b2c2
1  2021-05-28 -0.68606804  0.59848918 -1.30710356 -0.29626767  0.108031283 -0.175982140
2  2021-05-29 -0.08282104  0.05017292 -0.07843039  0.06135046  0.008423333  0.005935364
3  2021-05-30  0.62468579 -1.59924166 -0.41119329 -1.13268875 -0.038374446  0.054248120
4  2021-05-31  0.00780406 -0.05139295 -0.08067566  1.90463287  1.201815497  2.968438088
5  2021-06-01 -0.07186344 -0.08080991  0.34742254  0.99243873 -0.185489171 -0.272722771
6  2021-06-02  3.06467216 -2.89278864 -3.01397443 -0.77341778  1.044302702 -1.703161152
7  2021-06-03  0.22946735  0.38614963  0.41709268 -0.22316502 -0.857881519  0.623969018
8  2021-06-04  2.48789113 -0.19402639 -0.30162620  0.02889143 -0.036194437 -0.272813136
9  2021-06-05 -0.48172830  0.78173260 -0.79823906 -0.23864021 -0.037894774  0.096601990
10 2021-06-06  0.21070515 -0.55877763 -0.59279292  0.03171951 -0.082159505 -0.018002847
```

Check it for this extended dataset

```r
set.seed(123)
a1 <- rnorm(n = 10)
b1 <- rnorm(n = 10)
c1 <- rnorm(n = 10)
a2 <- rnorm(n = 10)
b2 <- rnorm(n = 10)
c2 <- rnorm(n = 10)
d2 <- rnorm(n = 10)

Original <- data.frame(
  date = seq(Sys.Date()-9, Sys.Date(), by = 1),
  a1 = a1,
  b1 = b1,
  c1 = c1,
  a2 = a2,
  b2 = b2,
  c2 = c2,
  d2 = d2)

library(tidyverse)
Original %>% pivot_longer(!date) %>%
  mutate(grp = gsub('^\\D*(\\d)+$', '\\1', name)) %>%
  group_split(grp, .keep = F) %>%
  map(~ .x %>% pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)) %>%
  map(~ combn(.x[-1], 2, FUN = Reduce, f = `*`) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
        setNames(combn(names(.x[-1]), 2, FUN = Reduce, f = paste0)) %>% cbind(.x[1], .)) %>%
  reduce(~left_join(.x, .y, by = 'date'))

         date        a1b1        a1c1        b1c1        a2b2         a2c2         a2d2         b2c2        b2d2        c2d2
1  2021-05-28 -0.68606804  0.59848918 -1.30710356 -0.29626767  0.108031283  0.161902656 -0.175982140 -0.26373820  0.09616971
2  2021-05-29 -0.08282104  0.05017292 -0.07843039  0.06135046  0.008423333  0.148221326  0.005935364  0.10444173  0.01433970
3  2021-05-30  0.62468579 -1.59924166 -0.41119329 -1.13268875 -0.038374446 -0.298262480  0.054248120  0.42163941  0.01428475
4  2021-05-31  0.00780406 -0.05139295 -0.08067566  1.90463287  1.201815497 -0.894445153  2.968438088 -2.20924515 -1.39402460
5  2021-06-01 -0.07186344 -0.08080991  0.34742254  0.99243873 -0.185489171 -0.880563395 -0.272722771 -1.29468307  0.24197936
6  2021-06-02  3.06467216 -2.89278864 -3.01397443 -0.77341778  1.044302702  0.209022041 -1.703161152 -0.34089562  0.46029226
7  2021-06-03  0.22946735  0.38614963  0.41709268 -0.22316502 -0.857881519  0.248271309  0.623969018 -0.18057692 -0.69416615
8  2021-06-04  2.48789113 -0.19402639 -0.30162620  0.02889143 -0.036194437 -0.003281582 -0.272813136 -0.02473471  0.03098700
9  2021-06-05 -0.48172830  0.78173260 -0.79823906 -0.23864021 -0.037894774 -0.282179411  0.096601990  0.71933645  0.11422674
10 2021-06-06  0.21070515 -0.55877763 -0.59279292  0.03171951 -0.082159505 -0.779997773 -0.018002847 -0.17091365  0.44269850
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I know it's the same but what do I need to change if I would like all combinations (ex: a1b1, b1a1 and not only a1b1)?

Comment: @Ian.T, I think there is no `permn` function in `utils`.  however, `combinat::permn` generates permutations of `n` elements taking all at once.  So you can use that in integration with `combn`.  If you are thinking of posting a separate question on that scenario, do tag me (here in this thread) and I'll try.

Answer (score 4):

Here is base R option -

```
cbind(Original[1], do.call(cbind, 
      unname(lapply(split.default(Original[-1], 
      gsub('\\D', '', names(Original[-1]))), function(x) {
           do.call(cbind, combn(names(x), 2, function(y) {
               setNames(data.frame(do.call(`*`, Original[y])), 
               paste0(y, collapse = ''))
  }, simplify = FALSE))
}))))

#         date     a1b1      a1c1    b1c1    a2b2    a2c2    b2c2
#1  2021-05-28 -0.06708  1.393018 -0.1213  0.1795 -1.0878 -0.0947
#2  2021-05-29  0.33234  0.045563  0.0201  0.0607  0.0247  0.9219
#3  2021-05-30  0.05043  0.160582  0.0341  0.1748 -0.3893 -0.1184
#4  2021-05-31  0.93642  0.980333  0.8156  0.0746 -1.1128 -0.1571
#5  2021-06-01 -1.21365 -0.256619  0.3268 -1.0106 -0.3542  2.1991
#6  2021-06-02 -0.09550  1.311417 -0.0754 -0.8243 -0.5532  1.1986
#7  2021-06-03  0.32514  0.373324  2.3262 -1.1904 -3.0764  0.7171
#8  2021-06-04 -0.41219  1.034527 -0.8338 -1.8588 -1.0202  2.6916
#9  2021-06-05  0.12488 -0.155639 -0.2294  0.2380  0.4288  0.3711
#10 2021-06-06 -0.00665  0.000139 -0.0105 -2.0117 -0.6363  1.0802
```

---

Explanation of the answer -

1. `split.default` is used to split the data in groups.

```
split.default(Original[-1], gsub('\\D', '', names(Original[-1])))

#$`1`
#         a1      b1      c1
#1  -0.87773  0.0764 -1.5871
#2   0.86812  0.3828  0.0525
#3   0.48761  0.1034  0.3293
#4  -1.06095 -0.8826 -0.9240
#5   0.97625 -1.2432 -0.2629
#6  -1.28910  0.0741 -1.0173
#7  -0.22843 -1.4234 -1.6343
#8  -0.71512  0.5764 -1.4467
#9   0.29108  0.4290 -0.5347
#10 -0.00937  0.7098 -0.0149

#$`2`
#        a2     b2     c2
#1  -1.4360 -0.125  0.758
#2  -0.0403 -1.507 -0.612
#3  -0.7580 -0.231  0.514
#4   0.7270  0.103 -1.531
#5  -0.4035  2.505  0.878
#6   0.6168 -1.336 -0.897
#7   2.2599 -0.527 -1.361
#8  -0.8394  2.215  1.215
#9  -0.5244 -0.454 -0.818
#10  1.0886 -1.848 -0.585
```

where `gsub` is used to remove all non-numeric character from the column names which is used to create groups.

```
gsub('\\D', '', names(Original[-1]))
#[1] "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "2"
```

2. For every group using `lapply` we create every combination of column names (`combn(names(x), 2.....`) taking 2 columns at a time.
3. Multiply each combination (`do.call(`*`, Original[y])`) create a one-column dataframe and give the name of the column using `setNames` that is name of the combination (`paste0(y, collapse = '')`)
4. All the combinations from step 3 are combined into one dataframe. (`do.call(cbind, combn.....`).
5. All such groups are again combined into one dataframe (`do.call(cbind, lapply...`).
6. First column with dates is kept as it is in the final output (`cbind(Original[1], ....`).

Comment: Brilliant answer @Ronak.  +1 already.  May be in some other re-birth I will be able to do this kinda work.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following solution, not as concise as other answers but here is a different approach that might have some points worthy of consideration. Much of the first chunk of codes I tried to emulate `combn` function with `tidyverse` equivalences. So first chuck which leads to `df2` data set creates all the combinations whose products you would like to calculate and the second chunk just evaluates them in the context of `Original` data set. Anyway thank you for this fantastic question that pushed me to the limits.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(rlang)

cols <- c("(\\w1)", "(\\w2)") 

cols %>% 
  map_dfc(~ names(Original)[str_detect(names(Original), .x)] %>%
            as_tibble() %>%
            mutate(value2 = rev(value)) %>%
            expand(value, value2) %>%
            filter(value != value2) %>%
            rowwise() %>%
            mutate(comb = paste0(sort(c(value, value2)), collapse = "*")) %>%
            select(comb) %>%
            distinct(comb)) %>%
  rename_with(~ str_remove(., "\\.\\.\\."), everything()) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c(".value", "id"), 
               names_pattern = "(\\w+)(\\d)") -> df2


df2 %>%
  select(comb) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(data = map(comb, ~ eval_tidy(parse_expr(.x), data = Original))) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(data)) %>%
  group_by(comb) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = comb, values_from = data) %>%
  relocate(ends_with("1")) %>%
  bind_cols(Original$date) %>%
  rename_with(~ str_remove(., "\\*"), everything()) %>%
  rename(Date = ...8) %>%
  relocate(Date) %>%
  select(-id)

# A tibble: 10 x 7
   Date           a1b1    a1c1      b1c1      a2b2     a2c2    b2c2
   <date>        <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2021-05-28 -0.129    0.0912 -0.0838   -1.55     -1.52     2.11  
 2 2021-05-29 -0.477   -1.58    0.352    -3.55     -0.144    0.101 
 3 2021-05-30  0.195    0.708   0.105     0.910    -0.356   -0.177 
 4 2021-05-31 -0.194    0.0219 -0.0111   -1.35      0.261   -0.200 
 5 2021-06-01  0.0140   0.107   0.000601 -0.0279   -0.126    0.104 
 6 2021-06-02  0.242    0.141   0.174    -0.0174    0.695   -0.0570
 7 2021-06-03 -0.439   -0.360   0.589     0.804    -2.76    -1.79  
 8 2021-06-04 -1.02    -0.0349  0.0137    2.07      0.357    0.495 
 9 2021-06-05 -0.00670  0.550  -0.00161  -0.000907  0.00503 -0.925 
10 2021-06-06 -0.287   -0.505   0.718    -0.0290   -0.00351  0.0256
```